# c++ with Qt creator on linux: Qtversion is invalid

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I just installed Qt creator to develop c++  on linux,

I try to start to build the smallest example, however I get this message:

:: error: The Qt version is invalid: Could not determine the path to the binaries of the Qt installation, maybe the qmake path is wrong?
 :: error: The qmake command "" was not found or is not executable.

in the build issues window

What should I do

Thank you

Comment: What distribution are you using, how did you install Qt Creator, and what is this smallest example you are talking about?

Comment: smallest example: I don't write anything and leave the default as is:#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}   I did not install Qt Creator but the computer support did, ditribution: Linux 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5.centos.plus
( if it helps)

Answer (score 1):

In the settings window on Qt4 tab there should be automaticaly-detected path to qmake. If there isn't one (or it is invalid) you should simply give the correct path. For this you have to locate qmake using the command window in linux: whereis qmake. Then on qt4 tab you should add manually the location (I particularly added: /usr/lib/qt4/bin/qmake).

Answer (score 0):

In the settings window on Qt4 tab there should be automaticaly-detected path to qmake. If there isn't one (or it is invalid) you should simply give the correct path.

Comment: I tried to do that but: (1) it is impossible to edit it- can not write there (2) what should i write there?  thank you

Comment: I don't know which version of qt-creator you have, but you should be able to click add button, which will open file-open dialog. You should specify location of your qmake executable. If you don't know where it is you can try to locate it using command `whereis qmake` in terminal. In case that there is more than one result, you should choose the one with `[...]/bin/[...]` in the path ;)

Comment: BTW: do you even have qt installed? as far as I know you can install qt-creator without qt-dev package.